# Converting VBA DDE communication code into Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba, dde

I have this VBA code that I would like to convert into Python. I am new to DDE, but I need this for a project. It works in VBA, but i need some additional features from Python, so it would be nice to have it all in the same language.

I tried some of these examples, but i dont really understand them. 
https://gist.github.com/noisywiz/2661065

'This is the code that works for me in excel VBA

```vb
Sub DDE_Write_RSLinx()

   DDEChannel = Application.DDEInitiate(app:="RSLinx", topic:="CTLGX")

   DDEItem = "DblIntArray1[1,0],L10,C10"

   Set RangeToPoke = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:J2")

   Set RangeToPoke = ActiveCell

   Application.DDEPoke DDEChannel, DDEItem, RangeToPoke

   Application.DDETerminate DDEChannel

End Sub
```

Anyone who knows about this DDE and Python

Comment: Do you have an instance of the `Excel.Application` class?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon do you mean like this:

`from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")`